# casperjs in openshift server

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, openshift, casperjs

In openshift server, we don't have root access that's why we can't install any npm package globally .

My question is how to setup and get working casperjs and phantomjs together in openshift server.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try a ready-to-use cartridge: https://github.com/daniel-sc/casperjs-cartridge

Comment: How to use this cartridge in openshift?

Comment: @jafarbtech I'm afraid this cartridge does not work with current version (3) of openshift.

Comment: Can you suggest any otherway to install casperjs app for free?

Comment: @jafarbtech I didn't use openshift 3 yet, but it [seems](https://docs.openshift.com/online/using_images/docker_images/index.html) that you can use any [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=casperjs&starCount=0)

Comment: thanks. can I install [this](https://github.com/rdpanek/docker_casperjs) Docker with `oc` command?

Comment: don't know about the `oc`command - you probably need to check our their documentation: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html

Answer (score 2):

In package.json, add the modules you want to install on OpenShift for your app inside "dependencies" object:

```
"dependencies": {
  "casperjs": "*",
  "phantomjs": "*",

  // other modules
}
```

Don't forget to commit and push the change onto OpenShift